# SerialPort class in .Net: a good idea?

Tags: .net-3.5, serial-port

I need to communicate through a rs232 serial port using a .Net application. A Win32 solution has already been coded, but we have trouble with ports that stay opened when we try to close them.

I found the class *SerialPort* in .Net Framework 3.5 and wanted to know if it is a good idea to use it or if there are some unresolved known issues.

Comment: It's always worked fine for me.

Comment: I prefer the .Net 4.0 version.  There was a serious problem when using USB serial port adapters and removing the adapter with the serial port open, which, from what I can tell, is fixed in 4.0.

Comment: @dbasnett : since we won't remove the adapter when it is opened, I think that using the framework 3.5 will be OK.

Comment: There were many other problems with the 3.5 version of the SerialPort.  I would suggest that you look at MSDN before deciding.  As I recall the only problem I had was the removal bug.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I always had a problem about receiving data off the RS232. Sometimes the event wouldn't fire when it received data from the port. This was a problem I had since using VS 2008 in C#/VB.Net.

One of the solutions I haven't tried yet is [OpenNETCF Serial Library](https://serial.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex but I read that it was developed using P/Invoke and it is much faster since it's on the kernel level, not within the framework. Though it was originally for the Compact Framework, it works just as well in regular version. I read so you need to maintain it yourself since it's not been updated for a long time, but then again, not much hasn't changed for RS232.

Maybe someone else can shed a light on the subject in regards to VS 2010/2012?